# Matrices Help --- Proving how its commutative

Tags: matrices, discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

I want someone to prove/ disprove that two 2x2 integer matrices are commutative. 
“The matrix product of any two 2x2 integer matrices is commutative”

Please do it in an easy way. I need to understand this,.

Thank You

Comment: Try with matrices $A,B$ with entries only $0$ or $1$, and compute $AB$ resp. $BA$.

Comment: By doing this what would we get, can you elaborate? Thanks

Comment: This is a $4$-dimensional vector space, so you can choose a basis, and test the matrices in the basis pairwise for commutation. If you find a non-commuting pair, you know matrix multiplication is not generally commutative. Should you find that all pairs commute, then _all_ matrix products will commute (by linearity of the matrix product). Just do the exercise!

Comment: Understanding this in words is very confusing, i was hoping for a more elaborate answer. Thank you for helping

Comment: @user97977, let $A=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1\\ 0 &0\end{pmatrix}$ and take any matrix $B$ with nonequal elements.

Comment: @njguliyev Can you tell me what a nonequal element is?

Comment: I mean *distinct*, like $B=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2\\ 3 & 4\end{pmatrix}$. Now just compute $AB$ and $BA$.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Any matrices at all? Pick a specific matrix $A$ and an arbitrary matrix $B=\left(\begin{array}{cc}a & b\\c & d\end{array}\right),$ and find $AB,BA$. As long as $A$ isn't a diagonal matrix, you should be able to choose $a,b,c,d$ to do the job.

Answer (score 2):

In order to prove that an operation is commutative on a set, you have to show that the equation
$$
AB = BA
$$
holds *for any* elements $A$ and $B$ in your set.  (For example, if the you are considering usual multiplication on the set of integers, this is true.)

Is it true for the set of $2 \times 2$ integer matrices?  If you suspect that it is false, then it suffices to come up with *any particular counterexample.*  Write down two matrices $A$ and $B$, and compute both products $AB$ and $BA$.  Are they the same?

Comment: I feel extremely brainless right now. This helped but i still cant understand completely -- so what i should do is make AB = BA and to do that i should substitute any value to see its reliability of the answer being commutative?

Comment: Choose any old matrices $A$ and $B$.  *Write them down!*  Per Dietrich's comment above, you might as well make your life easy and only use $1$s and $0$s for entries.  Now, multiply $AB$ and separately $BA$.  Compare the two results.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that you might get really unlucky (or lucky, depending on your perspective) and choose two matrices that just happen to commute, but that's quite unlikely.

Comment: So how exactly would that prove it? I just have to substitute my own values and compare? And luckily if they dont commute i have my answer? Is that what you mean?

Comment: *If it were true* that the set of $2 \times 2$ integer matrices were commutative, then **any** pair of matrices that you choose **must** commute.  So, your pair that doesn't commute proves that the operation is not commutative on the set.

Comment: An analogy:  suppose that I claimed that *every* mammalian species gives birth.  You can *disprove* this just by finding a single mammalian species that lays eggs:  platypus!

Comment: So basically i find a non-commutative set which will disprove the claim that 2x2 integer matrices are commutative? Thanks. I guess i understand now

Comment: You already have the set.  Just pick two members of the set!  Here:  I'll pick one.  $A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$.  Now, you pick a $B$ and compute both products.

Comment: Okay I did it for AB and for BA -- and i am assuming they are not commutative -- in other words AB ≠ BA -- Which would disprove the claim. Do i have my answer?

Comment: You are not **assuming** that they are not commutative.  You just **showed** that they are not commutative.  The point of these exercises is to practice logical argument.  The math (arithmetic, really) is not hard.  The challenge is in parsing the statement, and figuring out how to address it.  Your calculation of the two products $AB$ and $BA$ is the heart of your argument.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counterexample

Comment: Got it! I guess it was really simple

Comment: Please select this answer if it was useful to you.  Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

To prove that the statement is false (in general), all you have to do is find two particular $2 \times 2$ matrices $A$ and $B$ with the property that $AB \ne BA$.

So, try some specific examples, at random. You can use matrices that consist of 0's and 1's, to make the arithmetic easy.

One of two things will happen:

(1) You will find two matrices that don't commute. Then you're done -- we only need one counterexample to show that the general statement is false, or ...

(2) If you try a few dozen examples, and you find that every pair commutes, then you might start to suspect that the statement is true, in general. Then, you'd have to prove it. If/when you get to that point, ask again, and someone will help you.

Comment: No, i figured it would be easier to disprove it, since i know that the only way it can be commutative is by finding the multiples of the matrix being commutative. thanks